# How to use int or floor to compute coordinates

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I want to illustrate the approximation of the volume under a surface with a double Riemann sum. I am drawing 3d boxes over a 6x6 rectangular grid, from back to front, left to right (painter's algorithm). Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\hfil\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = middle,
xmin=-1,xmax=7,
ymin=-1,ymax=7,
zmin = 0, zmax = 2,
ticks = none
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,18}{
    \draw [fill=red] ({#1-int(#1/6)*6},{6-int(#1/6)},0)
    -- ++(axis direction cs:1,0,0)
    -- ++(axis direction cs:0,0,{0.02*((6-int(#1/6))^2+(#1-int(#1/6)*6)^2)})
    -- ++(axis direction cs:-1,0,0)
    -- cycle;
    \draw [fill=red] ({#1-int(#1/6)*6+1},{6-int(#1/6)},0)
    -- ++(axis direction cs:0,1,0)
    -- ++(axis direction cs:0,0,{0.02*((6-int(#1/6))^2+(#1-int(#1/6)*6)^2)})
    -- ++(axis direction cs:0,-1,0)
    -- cycle;
    \draw [fill=red] ({#1-int(#1/6)*6},{6-int(#1/6)},{0.02*((6-int(#1/6))^2+(#1-int(#1/6)*6)^2)})
    -- ++(axis direction cs:0,1,0)
    -- ++(axis direction cs:1,0,0)
    -- ++(axis direction cs:0,-1,0);
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and here is the (correct) picture that the code creates:

[image: 18 boxes]

However, if I add one more box by changing the range of `\pdfplotsinvokeforeach` to `{0,...,18}`, the next box is incorrectly positioned:

[image: 19 boxes]

But then, the boxes after that, up to 36, are correctly positioned!
[image: 36 boxes]

Some numerical problem occurs for 18 and I do not know how to fix it. I tried `floor` instead of `int`, no luck (I was not able to get `mod` to work either, but it does not affect me).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed rounding errors in computing `int(#1/6)*6`.  These may be overcome by using something like `int((#1+.5)/6)*6` instead.

I suggest putting most your quantities in some local macros, to make the code more transparent, and to avoid copying errors.  It is easier to do this with the ungrouped version of `\pgfplotsforeach...` combined with an internal `\edef` as demonstrated in the `pgfplots` documentation.

I have deliberately changed the colours, just to see what each `\draw` command is doing.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\hfil\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = middle,
xmin=-1,xmax=7,
ymin=-1,ymax=7,
zmin = 0, zmax = 2,
ticks = none
]
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x in {0,...,18} {
    \def\xxt{int((\x+.5)/6)}
    \def\xx{\x-\xxt*6}
    \def\yy{6-\xxt}
    \def\hh{0.02*((\yy)^2+(\xx)^2)}
    \edef\temp{
    \noexpand\draw [fill=green] ({\xx},{\yy},0)
    -- ++(axis direction cs:1,0,0)
    -- ++(axis direction cs:0,0,{\hh})
    -- ++(axis direction cs:-1,0,0)
    -- cycle;
    \noexpand\draw [fill=red] ({\xx+1},{\yy},0)
    -- ++(axis direction cs:0,1,0)
    -- ++(axis direction cs:0,0,{\hh})
    -- ++(axis direction cs:0,-1,0)
    -- cycle;
    \noexpand\draw [fill=blue] ({\xx},{\yy},{\hh})
    -- ++(axis direction cs:0,1,0)
    -- ++(axis direction cs:1,0,0)
    -- ++(axis direction cs:0,-1,0);
    }
    \temp
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```